# PHP parse files function - Save to DB

Tags: php, mysql, loops, parsing, bittorrent

I have been at this most of the day today, so I normally have success with iterations and working with keys/values. This time its not easy easy it seems, running back and forth between the php docs and trailing difference sources, no luck but this is as close as I came.

So in this code, we are **checking ../../uploads** for all *.torrent files and **parsing each one and saving as BLOB => database**.

The code works wonderfully, with individual uploads. So I decided to loop it all together and send all of the files to the database based on their DB ID / FILE ID (which all match). So the logic there was easy.

This is the code I have

```
// Start parsing files => DB => LONGGLOB
foreach (glob("../../uploads/*.torrent") as $filename) {
    
    // Match file ID with database ID (WHERE CLAUS)
    $fileid = str_replace('.torrent', '', $filename);
    $filename1 = str_replace('../../uploads/', '', $filename);
    
    $fp = fopen('../../uploads/'.$filename1, 'rb');
    //$fp = fopen($_FILES['torrent']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
    $data = '';
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $data .= fread($fp, 8192);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    $arr = bdecode($data);
    if ($arr === false) {
        die('invalid torrent');
    }

    // TODO: more validity checks for torrent?
    
    if (!array_key_exists('info', $arr)) {
        die('invalid torrent');
    }

    $arr['info']['private'] = 1;

    $infobc = bencode($arr['info']);
    if ($infobc === false) {
        die('bencoding error');
    }

    $info_hash = sha1($infobc);
    $total_size = 0;

    if (array_key_exists('files', $arr['info'])) {
        foreach ($arr['info']['files'] as $file) {
            if (array_key_exists('length', $file)) {
                $total_size += $file['length'];
            }
        }
    } else if (array_key_exists('length', $arr['info'])) {
        $total_size += $arr['info']['length'];
    }
    
    $description = 'dsfsdfDESCR';
    $name = 'dsfsdfNAME';

    // BEncode data and send it to DB
    $data = bencode($arr);
    $an = array_key_exists('anonymous', $_POST);
    $db->query_params("UPDATE torrents SET user_id = :user_id, name = :name, descr = :description, anon = :anonymous, data = :data, info_hash = :info_hash, size = :total_size WHERE torrent_id = :torrentid", array('user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['user_id'], 'name' => $name, 'description' => $description, 'anonymous' => $db->encode_bool($an), 'data' => $data, 'info_hash' => $info_hash, 'total_size' => $total_size, 'torrentid' => $fileid)) or die('db error');
}
```

I got it looping each file finally. But the issue now is it is revealing the first file, but its not continuing on and actually parsing file by file (lowest ID => highest ID, either order), producing errors in a snow ball effect.

I've made many many attempts already, down to complaints about fopen() 1st param, so I fixed that, now its not iterating properly. I believe its my logic here and i can't understand it.

So **$data = bencode($arr)** needs to parse each metafile and send it as it does perfectly with upload form as commented out ($fp). Any help is appreciated.

I've listed files using all different methods, this time its the blob function. How can I iterate each file and parse it => next file ??

The commented sections are perfectly working. But we need to parse per-file-id basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered another one myself again. I gotta stop running here at my last option, anyways this is the solution for those who need it. I got it an hour later and I thank php.net gratefully!

Solution:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator('../../uploads');
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            $getthelist = $fileinfo->getFilename();
            $fp         = fopen('../../uploads/' . $getthelist, 'rb');
            $data       = '';
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $data .= fread($fp, 8192);
            }
            fclose($fp);
            $arr = bdecode($data);
            if ($arr === false) {
                die('invalid torrent');
            }
            if (!array_key_exists('info', $arr)) {
                die('invalid torrent');
            }
            $arr['info']['private'] = 1;
            $infobc                 = bencode($arr['info']);
            if ($infobc === false) {
                die('bencoding error');
            }
            $info_hash  = sha1($infobc);
            $total_size = 0;
            if (array_key_exists('files', $arr['info'])) {
                foreach ($arr['info']['files'] as $file) {
                    if (array_key_exists('length', $file)) {
                        $total_size += $file['length'];
                    }
                }
            } else if (array_key_exists('length', $arr['info'])) {
                $total_size += $arr['info']['length'];
            }
            $fileid = str_replace('.torrent', '', $getthelist);
            $data   = bencode($arr);
            $an     = array_key_exists('anonymous', $_POST);
            DB::run("UPDATE torrents SET data = :data, info_hash = :info_hash, size = :total_size WHERE torrent_id = :torrentid", array(
                'data' => $data,
                'info_hash' => $info_hash,
                'total_size' => $total_size,
                'torrentid' => $fileid
            )) or die('db error');
        }
    }
}
```

**DirectoryIterator()** was the answer here. While other methods worked, they were not as efficient or logical as this way. It works perfectly as expected.